# Work done in Brayton cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I am studying Brayton cycle. In Brayton cycle, heat addition and exhaust is carried out at constant pressure. Now, the efficiency is $$\eta=\frac {w_{net}}{q_{in}}$$
My book, while calculating $w_{net}$ for efficiency takes into account only the compressor work and the turbine work. My doubt is shouldn't the work in constant pressure heat addition and extraction be also taken into account.

Thanks 
[image: problem in book(Engineering Thermodynamics by Cengel Boles]

I have added the image of book problem. The book is Engineering Thermodynamics by Cengel Boles. It is an example problem. In (c) part I have to calculate efficiency. Just have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, the work is present not only during compression and expansion, but also during heating and cooling at constant pressure. Could you please write down the calculations? Maybe there is some term which cancel out.

Comment: Has the book stated any assumptions?

Comment: I have added the image. Please have a look at it. @SolarMike

Comment: Rigorously, it seems wrong, if we consider the operation performed in a piston with four phases. However, considering how it is performed in reality, it is probably correct, as @BobD explains. I still have a doubt, if the efficiency (with the usually reported formula) is calculated for the "ideal" piston cycle or for the "real" compressor-turbine cycle. When I will have time, I will calculate it.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli    What makes you think work is done during the constant pressure processes? The volume changes are not against anything (like expansion of a gas in a piston/cylinder). Your basically dealing with heat exchangers. Also why are you referring to the efficiency of an "ideal" piston cycle? The Brayton Cycle involves shaft work (compressor and turbine).

Comment: The Brayton cycle I have in mind uses a piston: i) isobaric heating with piston expansion, ii) adiabatic expansion with piston expansion; iii) isobaric compression with piston compression; iv) adiabatic compression with piston compression. But in the "real" cycle, I perfectly agree with @BobD.

Comment: @DorianoBrogioli You can certainly envision a cycle like that, but it is not the Brayton Cycle.The Brayton cycle (also called the Joule cycle) represents the operation of a gas turbine engine, not a piston/cylinder engine. The gas turbine application is the one presented by Tojrah and the reason why no work is involved in the constant pressure processes.

Comment: When we represent the cycle in the T-S graph, we can imagine to follow it reversibly (quasi-stationarily). This is called the "underlying" reversible (or ideal) cycle. In the case of Brayton cycle, the "ideal" cycle is with the isobaric expansion against something. The real cycle will follow the same path in T-S, but with losses of free energy.

Answer (score 0):

The Brayton cycle (or Joule cycle) represents the operation of a gas turbine engine.

For the gas turbine operation the constant pressure heat addition process is an idealization of the combustion process. No pressure volume work is involved

The constant pressure heat extraction process simply cools the air to its original state. Its basically a condenser. Again no pressure volume work is involved.

Bottom line, the constant pressure processes are basically heat exchange processes where

$$Q=C_{p}\Delta T$$

Here is another resource for the Brayton Cycle

http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/SPRING/propulsion/notes/node27.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what does the area under that curve indicate? It is clear that it is a non zero quantity

Comment: Area under which curve? 1-4 or 2-3?

Comment: Each of them....

Comment: @Tojrah The area under the TS diagram (2-3 and 1-4) is heat.

Comment: @Tojrah The constant pressure processes are basically heat exchangers. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Comment: @Tojrah No problem. Hope it helps.